# y axis value getting changes on highchart redraw()

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have added the redraw function on highchart to update the icon for point but after redraw, y-value of point is getting updated on y-axis. How to avoid it?
Below is the code which I used for highchart,

redraw() function ->

```
 redraw: function () {
            chart.series[1].points.forEach(function (point, index) {
              let type = point.options.type;
              if (type !== 'VAN') {
                let symbol = '\uf21a';

                let angle = 90;
                let offsetY = -23;
                let offsetX = 0;
                point.update({
                  marker: {
                    symbol: 'this property required to be set',
                    fontAwesomeConfig: {
                      symbol: 'text:' + symbol,
                      customizeFn: function (svgElem, x, y, w, h, options) {
                        return svgElem.attr({
                          translateY: h + offsetY,
                          translateX: offsetX,
                          rotate: angle,
                        })
                          .css({
                            fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
                            fontSize: '14px',
                            'font-weight': 900,
                          });
                      },
                    },
                  },
                }, false);
              }
            });
            chart.redraw();
          },
```

y-axis configuration ->

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: Labels.get('meta.label.RTTEP.RemainingDays'),
      align: 'high',
    },
    tickInterval: 10,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
      //step: 1,
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function () {
        return this.value - shift;
      },
    },
    plotLines: [{
      className: 'zero-percent-line',
      value: shift,
    }],
  },
```

how to achieve it, can someone please guide?

Comment: Could you please reproduce this behaviour in the online demo? You can start here:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eLo7q2pu/